# Group by and then flatten the items

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of objects with the following properties:

```
int TownId, int CompanyId, int ProductId, int[] Prices
```

I want to turn this into a list of `TownCompany` objects; each item having the following properties:

```
int TownId, int CompanyId, int[] Products, int[] Prices
```

So I can do

```
flatList.GroupBy(l => new { l.TownId, l.CompanyId })
```

To get a list of groups, which has all the products and prices for each town/company pair. Now, for each key in this lookup, I want to flatten/merge all the values. Seems like I should be able to use `SelectMany`, but I always get a bit confused by what projections to supply to it...

How do I turn this list of groups into a list of flattened lists for each key? I hope I've made sense.

Example:

If my original list is this:

```
new[] {
    new Item { TownId = 1, CompanyId = 10, ProductId = 100, Prices = new [] { 1, 2 } },
    new Item { TownId = 1, CompanyId = 10, ProductId = 101, Prices = new [] { 3 } },
};
```

I want a list that looks like this:

```
{
    { TownId: 1, CompanyId: 10, Products: [100, 101], Prices: [1, 2, 3] }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then something like this:

```
flatList.GroupBy(l => new { l.TownId, l.CompanyId })
        .Select(g => new 
        {
            TownId = g.Key.TownId,
            CompanyId = g.Key.CompanyId,   
            Products = g.Select(o => o.ProductId).ToArray(),
            Prices = g.SelectMany(o => o.Prices).ToArray()
        });
```

Comment: No, not quite there, I've added an example to clarify. This creates separate items for each product, whereas I want them combined.

Comment: a little "collaboration" there between the two answerers, but yours compiles and works first! Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamClark "Collaboration" is an entirely unfit word to describe what happened.

Answer (score 18):

You need `SelectMany` only for `Prices`; for `ProductId` it's a simple `Select`:

```
flatList
.GroupBy(l => new { l.TownId, l.CompanyId })
.Select(g => new {
    g.Key.TownId
,   g.Key.CompanyId
,   ProductIds = g.Select(o => o.ProductId).ToArray()
,   Prices = g.SelectMany(o => o.Prices).ToArray()
});
```

Comment: I get "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Comment: @GrahamClark This is now fixed.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is still not fixed. You probably already know this, but the `Select` method takes a `Func<TSource, TResult>` or `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` as a second parameter. As for now you're sending in an anonymous object as parameter. It doesn't know what `g` is.

Comment: @Mario Since you're above 2K, you can freely edit answers of others, and your edits will show up right away without waiting for an approval. Copying someone else's answer as yours is not the right course of action, unless the fix is rather substantial (which is definitely not the case here).

Comment: Easy there. I actually created the code without your answer as soon as I saw the edit on the question and understood what the OP meant. Since I already had given an answer, I hurried to create the new solution and didn't even notice until after what you had answered. The only thing I copied from you later was `.ToArray()`.

Comment: @Mario Sure, you did. And you also picked the same names for every single variable in the lambdas by pure coincidence. Seriously, though, when you make a mistake, it's best to acknowledge it, and move on. It spares everyone some aggravation.

Comment: Well, at least he altered the line breaks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I really did create it on my own. Obviously I can't prove it to you and with my low reputation compared to yours I am at a disadvantage to be believed. Feel free to compare my other answers if it helps, though I doubt it will. Just trying to help out here. So, I can delete my answer if you want, don't really care =/

Comment: The up votes are a bit funny though. The code shouldn't compile, but I guess it is useful =)

Comment: @Mario "with my low reputation compared to yours I am at a disadvantage to be believed" reputation has nothing to do with general credibility, only the technical one. You shouldn't delete your answer either, because it is technically 100% correct (you can't delete it either, because it is accepteed). Moreover, I believe the two downvotes of a correct answer were a mistake, so I upvoted to compensate for it.

Comment: @Mario I guess the only thing to remember for the future is that if what you are about to post looks like something that's been posted for a while, give or take a few syntax errors, a prudent course of action is to edit, rather than post as new. This would avoid a possibility of superficial allegations, no matter how unfounded they might be. Good luck!

Comment: I was referring to the users downvoting. They don't know who is correct or who is wrong, so I'm thinking that they look at reputation and saying *that guy must be wrong, because he has way lower reputation and that must mean he doesn't know as much*, so I do believe they use reputation as credibility in this case. But I got your point ;) I will take this with me in the future. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @Mario I am reasonably certain that they were not guided by reputation, only by the Graham's second comment and my comment on your answer. Four up-votes on my comment is an indirect confirmation of that. By the way, 2.5K+ reputation is more than respectable - it's top 1.2% of all users on Stack Overflow!